# matlab check index of matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a very simple question to you. What is the fastest and cleanest way to check if an index exceeds the array bounds of an 2D array.

i have something like that

```
function Idx_bool = isIndexValid(ArrayRow,ArrayCol,idx_row,idx_col)

   Idx_bool =true;

   if(idx_row>ArrayRow || idx_col> ArrayCol || idx_row<=0 || idx_col<=0)

        Idx_bool = false;    

   end

end
```

with ArrayRow, ArrayCol = size of my 2D array.

and idx_row, idx_col = Index to be checked.

is there maybe a matlab function that checks automatically if the index is correct? Or is there a better way to do this? 
I use this code in a for loop and therefore it should be as fast as possible.

Comment: Surely it is faster to avoid the `if` altogether -> `Idx_bool = (idx_row<=ArrayRow && idx_col<= ArrayCol && idx_row>0 && idx_col>0)`, however, you probably also want to make sure that indices are integers. Lastly, there is an approach that says you don't need to test the indices at all - just try to access the matrix at these indices (inside `try`-`catch`) and if it fails - just print a message of some sort or perform a fallback. Regarding loops - if all indices are available in advance, you can perform the check once for all of them together (in that case, you need to replace `&&` with `&`).

Comment: Thank you very much ! Unfortunately I dont have all indices in advance. But I think the `try`- `catch` approach is a very good solution to my task.

Comment: if this is for a larger function to check the input once, have a look at `validateattributes` or the `inputParser`